# .net RESTful API authorization for react app requests using Active Directory access token

Tags: .net, reactjs, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have a React app using MSAL to log in using Azure Active Directory, when user logs in MSAL return an IDToken and an AccessToken.

I have a RESTfull API using  ASP NetCore MVC, I want to implement a middleware that only returns data when the AccessToken is on Authentication header as Bearer.

Where can I find clear docs of which libraries should I use?
I cant find a clear way of doing this on the Azure docs, only if i run an asp web app, i want to keep the api and the front end separated.

I've already tried using 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

but it returns 401 using the access token

This is my current middleware, which does not work using the ADAccess Token:

```
services.AddMvc(o => {
   // Requires authentication across the API
   o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(Policies.Default));
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

services.AddAuthorization(o => {
   o.AddPolicy(Policies.Default, policy => {
      policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();                 
   });
   o.AddPolicy(Policies.ReadTodoItems, policy => {
      policy.RequirePermissions(delegated: new[] { Scopes.TodosRead, Scopes.TodosReadWrite },
application: new[] { AppRoles.TodosRead, AppRoles.TodosReadWrite });
   });
   o.AddPolicy(Policies.WriteTodoItems, policy => {
      policy.RequirePermissions(delegated: new[] { Scopes.TodosReadWrite }, application: new[] { AppRoles.TodosReadWrite });
   });
});

services.AddAuthentication(o => {
   o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o => {
   o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
   o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters {
      ValidAudiences = new List<string>
      {
         Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
         Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
      }
   };
});

services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformation, AzureAdScopeClaimTransformation>();
```

I expect to get 200 on my api request using my bearer Access token but it always returns 401: unauthorized

#### MSAL code to get acces token on React APP

```
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msal'

const applicationConfig = {
  clientID: "your-client-id",
  authority: "your-authority-uri",
  graphScopes: ["scope"]
};


const Msal = new UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, null, { storeAuthStateInCookie: false })

export default async () => {
  // token request
  await Msal.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes)
  const accessToken = await Msal.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes)
}
```

I've tried using ADAL too, its the same case.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the API to identify what is causing it to fail? Can you include the code you use to obtain the access token?

Comment: Can you include what scopes you are using? You'll need to use e.g. `your-api-app-id-uri/.default`